# ¿Cómo especificar puerto de selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Deseo usar selenium pero abrirlo en un puerto en específico. ¿Cómo podría realizar esto?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(port=1234)
driver.get("https://www.google.com.ar")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57612692/1264820

Comment: Buenas, copie y pegue ese codigo para probarlo pero me sale el siguiente error: 
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'

Comment: Fíjate que dice que eso estará soportado en la siguiente versión. La respuesta es de agosto de 2019. Igual esa "siguiente versión" aún no está disponible (o no es la que tú tienes)